# Create Database under MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm new to MongoDB (only used Mysql / PhpMyadmin before).
I created my database (I don't know if this is the word) with this command:

```
`php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:schema:create`
```

Return this

Created dbs for all classes
Created collections for all classes
Created indexes for all classes

Then I made this

```
`php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:generate:documents AppBundle`
```

> Generating documents for "AppBundle"
>   Generating AppBundle\Document\MessageUser

What I don't understand is when I look with Studio 3T the MessageUser Collection I don't see all the fields that should be mapped

There is only an id but I should have more field mapped.

[image]

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Doctrine ODM, but judging by how those commands relate to ORM using a database like MySQL, I don't understand your approach. For me it reads like: first you generate the schema from the models (Documents) and then you generate the Models from the schema. Could you maybe show how the MessageUserCollection is supposed to look and how it looks? From what source was the schema generated?

Comment: @dbrumann I've added a sample of how it looks like.

Comment: Have you tried running `doctrine:mongodb:mapping:info`?

Comment: Found 1 documents mapped in document manager default:
[OK]   AppBundle\Document\MessageUser